# Building JDK 8 sources with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, compilation, java-8

Out of pure curiosity, I want to browse Java sources in Eclipse in order to benefit the ease of navigation and search.

When I import sources into a newly created project, I encounter thousands of errors, how do I correct these errors ?

Comment: Are you loading JDK sources to compile them from Eclipse and get a JDK build or do you want to add the sources to your Eclipse just to see the implementation of certain methods?

Comment: Figure out what is wrong and fix it :/ I don't know what kind of answer can be given to such an open ended question. At least provide an example of a compile error you get, and detail the steps you took to "import" the code.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza both in fact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sources of the JDK are located in JDK_HOME/src.zip

- Unzip this archive in the folder of your choice.
- Create a new Java Project under Eclipse
- Import the content of src.zip into your new project. The compiler will raise several errors.

First, you need to add JDK_HOME/lib/tools.jar to your build path. Into project properties, go to Build Path, libraries and add external Jar.

Second, you need to give access to normally restricted classes from the JDK. From the libraries pane, click the JRE system library and select Access rules. Set the resolution to accessible for the rule pattern */**. This gives access to all the classes in the JRE jars.
[image]

Finally, there are two classes that have been reported missing since JDK7 that you have to import manually. There are various solutions , the fastest for me is to download from OpenJDK repositories :

- [sun.awt.UNIXToolkit.java](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u60/jdk/file/935758609767/src/solaris/classes/sun/awt/UNIXToolkit.java)
- [sun.font.FontConfigManager.java](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u60/jdk/file/935758609767/src/solaris/classes/sun/font/FontConfigManager.java)

Enjoy browsing Java sources !

Comment: Careful. The question title is about compile JDK sources, not to import them into Eclipse.

Comment: When importing the sources into an Eclipse Java project, compilation will be automatically (unless you set it otherwise) started.

Answer (score 3):

There is no reason to import the JDK sources as a project in Eclipse or try to compile them. If you [have Eclipse pointed to a JDK](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM) (as opposed to a JRE), it will automatically pick up the `src.zip` that it finds there and show source when you browse to JDK classes.

**Package Explorer**, **Project Explorer**, **Java Browsing**, and other Java-oriented views show the packages and classes just as they were any other library/JAR. In **Package Explorer** they show up under **JRE System Library**.

[image]

In **Java Browsing** perspective, it looks like any other packages:

[image]

Comment: I needed this, obviously with no more reason than needing it. So I thought it may interest others.

Comment: Actually this question is interesting for those folks who want to develop a patch for OpenJDK using Eclipse.

Comment: @TagirValeev if that were true, **NONE** of the answers covers it.

Comment: You don't have the package explorer using this solution. Or I am missing something.

Comment: Yes, the packages and classes are presented in all views. I updated the answer with some screen shots.

Comment: I don't think it's ok to tell someone "there is no reason", either answer it or don't bother. Just my opinion.